# Stanford CoreNLP server's JSON response missing RelationExtractor annotations

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server, corenlp-server

I'm processing a simple sentence to test Stanford's **RelationExtractor**:

> Microsoft is based in New York.

(it's not)

When I'm annotating the sentence in Java, by directly using the CoreNLP jar files I get the wanted result - CoreNLP finds a **OrgBased_In** relation between *Microsoft* and *New York*.

```
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
    relationType = sentence.get(MachineReadingAnnotations.RelationMentionsAnnotation.class).get(0).type // => OrgBased_In
}
```

However, sending the same sentence into the [CoreNLP Server](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) like so:

```
curl --data 'Microsoft is based in New York.' 'http://localhost:9000/?properties={%22annotators%22%3A%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Cpos%2Clemma%2Cner%2Cparse%2Cdepparse%2Crelation%22%2C%22outputFormat%22%3A%22json%22}' -o -
```

Results in a json response that contains no data on relations whatsoever:

```
{'sentences': [{'basicDependencies': [{'dep': 'ROOT',
                                   'dependent': 3,
                                   'dependentGloss': 'based',
                                   'governor': 0,
                                   'governorGloss': 'ROOT'},
                                  {'dep': 'nsubjpass',
                                   'dependent': 1,
                                   'dependentGloss': 'Microsoft',
                                   'governor': 3,
                                   'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                  {'dep': 'auxpass',
                                   'dependent': 2,
                                   'dependentGloss': 'is',
                                   'governor': 3,
                                   'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                  {'dep': 'case',
                                   'dependent': 4,
                                   'dependentGloss': 'in',
                                   'governor': 6,
                                   'governorGloss': 'York'},
                                  {'dep': 'compound',
                                   'dependent': 5,
                                   'dependentGloss': 'New',
                                   'governor': 6,
                                   'governorGloss': 'York'},
                                  {'dep': 'nmod',
                                   'dependent': 6,
                                   'dependentGloss': 'York',
                                   'governor': 3,
                                   'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                  {'dep': 'punct',
                                   'dependent': 7,
                                   'dependentGloss': '.',
                                   'governor': 3,
                                   'governorGloss': 'based'}],
            'enhancedDependencies': [{'dep': 'ROOT',
                                      'dependent': 3,
                                      'dependentGloss': 'based',
                                      'governor': 0,
                                      'governorGloss': 'ROOT'},
                                     {'dep': 'nsubjpass',
                                      'dependent': 1,
                                      'dependentGloss': 'Microsoft',
                                      'governor': 3,
                                      'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                     {'dep': 'auxpass',
                                      'dependent': 2,
                                      'dependentGloss': 'is',
                                      'governor': 3,
                                      'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                     {'dep': 'case',
                                      'dependent': 4,
                                      'dependentGloss': 'in',
                                      'governor': 6,
                                      'governorGloss': 'York'},
                                     {'dep': 'compound',
                                      'dependent': 5,
                                      'dependentGloss': 'New',
                                      'governor': 6,
                                      'governorGloss': 'York'},
                                     {'dep': 'nmod:in',
                                      'dependent': 6,
                                      'dependentGloss': 'York',
                                      'governor': 3,
                                      'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                     {'dep': 'punct',
                                      'dependent': 7,
                                      'dependentGloss': '.',
                                      'governor': 3,
                                      'governorGloss': 'based'}],
            'enhancedPlusPlusDependencies': [{'dep': 'ROOT',
                                              'dependent': 3,
                                              'dependentGloss': 'based',
                                              'governor': 0,
                                              'governorGloss': 'ROOT'},
                                             {'dep': 'nsubjpass',
                                              'dependent': 1,
                                              'dependentGloss': 'Microsoft',
                                              'governor': 3,
                                              'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                             {'dep': 'auxpass',
                                              'dependent': 2,
                                              'dependentGloss': 'is',
                                              'governor': 3,
                                              'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                             {'dep': 'case',
                                              'dependent': 4,
                                              'dependentGloss': 'in',
                                              'governor': 6,
                                              'governorGloss': 'York'},
                                             {'dep': 'compound',
                                              'dependent': 5,
                                              'dependentGloss': 'New',
                                              'governor': 6,
                                              'governorGloss': 'York'},
                                             {'dep': 'nmod:in',
                                              'dependent': 6,
                                              'dependentGloss': 'York',
                                              'governor': 3,
                                              'governorGloss': 'based'},
                                             {'dep': 'punct',
                                              'dependent': 7,
                                              'dependentGloss': '.',
                                              'governor': 3,
                                              'governorGloss': 'based'}],
            'index': 0,
            'parse': '(ROOT\n'
                     '  (S\n'
                     '    (NP (NNP Microsoft))\n'
                     '    (VP (VBZ is)\n'
                     '      (VP (VBN based)\n'
                     '        (PP (IN in)\n'
                     '          (NP (NNP New) (NNP York)))))\n'
                     '    (. .)))',
            'tokens': [{'after': ' ',
                        'before': '',
                        'characterOffsetBegin': 0,
                        'characterOffsetEnd': 9,
                        'index': 1,
                        'lemma': 'Microsoft',
                        'ner': 'ORGANIZATION',
                        'originalText': 'Microsoft',
                        'pos': 'NNP',
                        'word': 'Microsoft'},
                       {'after': ' ',
                        'before': ' ',
                        'characterOffsetBegin': 10,
                        'characterOffsetEnd': 12,
                        'index': 2,
                        'lemma': 'be',
                        'ner': 'O',
                        'originalText': 'is',
                        'pos': 'VBZ',
                        'word': 'is'},
                       {'after': ' ',
                        'before': ' ',
                        'characterOffsetBegin': 13,
                        'characterOffsetEnd': 18,
                        'index': 3,
                        'lemma': 'base',
                        'ner': 'O',
                        'originalText': 'based',
                        'pos': 'VBN',
                        'word': 'based'},
                       {'after': ' ',
                        'before': ' ',
                        'characterOffsetBegin': 19,
                        'characterOffsetEnd': 21,
                        'index': 4,
                        'lemma': 'in',
                        'ner': 'O',
                        'originalText': 'in',
                        'pos': 'IN',
                        'word': 'in'},
                       {'after': ' ',
                        'before': ' ',
                        'characterOffsetBegin': 22,
                        'characterOffsetEnd': 25,
                        'index': 5,
                        'lemma': 'New',
                        'ner': 'LOCATION',
                        'originalText': 'New',
                        'pos': 'NNP',
                        'word': 'New'},
                       {'after': '',
                        'before': ' ',
                        'characterOffsetBegin': 26,
                        'characterOffsetEnd': 30,
                        'index': 6,
                        'lemma': 'York',
                        'ner': 'LOCATION',
                        'originalText': 'York',
                        'pos': 'NNP',
                        'word': 'York'},
                       {'after': '',
                        'before': '',
                        'characterOffsetBegin': 30,
                        'characterOffsetEnd': 31,
                        'index': 7,
                        'lemma': '.',
                        'ner': 'O',
                        'originalText': '.',
                        'pos': '.',
                        'word': '.'}]}]}
```

I can see on the CoreNLP server terminal that the relation extraction model *is* loaded.

```
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.RelationExtractorAnnotator - Loading relation model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/supervised_relation_extractor/roth_relation_model_pipelineNER.ser
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ultimately nobody added that output to the JSON for that annotator, which we can do eventually.

Right now the relation extraction we are mainly supporting is the new `kbp` annotator.  This extracts the relations from the TAC-KBP challenge.

You can find the relation descriptions here:
https://tac.nist.gov//2015/KBP/ColdStart/guidelines/TAC_KBP_2015_Slot_Descriptions_V1.0.pdf

Here is an example command that I ran:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,entitymentions,coref,kbp -file microsoft-example.txt -outputFormat json
```

If you look at the JSON you'll see the proper relation has been extracted.

Comment: My goal eventually is to train a relation extractor model using new relation types, so I think KBP is not what I'm looking for. I guess I'll have to roll out my own wrapper for the relation extractor. Thanks for the quick reply!